# Poplulate a specific column when a row is added to a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using the following code to update the database.

```
int lastRow = inventoryDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
inventoryDataGridView.Rows[lastRow].Cells[1].Value = variableName;
```

However, if multiple rows are added before the database is saved then it will only save the last one. So then I tried this code.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.inventoryDataGridView.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[1].Value = variableName;
}
```

The problem with this is that it will update every cell in the given column to include the cells that already have a value. This is not efficient. Any suggestions on how to update just the given column of the newly added rows?

Thank You.

Comment: What event(s) are you handling?

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to add the string held in the variableName to the second column of all the newly added rows not just the last row. I believe counting starts at 0 so it would actually be column 1. I was thinking there could be an event changed method I could use every time a new row is added. I tried to look on the MSDN website for the event changed method but I could not get the website to come up. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to serve my purpose. As soon as I start typing in the blank row it will add another row to the datagridview and populate the given column of the new row I am entering with the variableName value.

```
private void inventoryDataGridView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    int lastRow = inventoryDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
    inventoryDataGridView.Rows[lastRow - 1].Cells[2].Value = accountNumber;
}
```